# Advices for first mechanical keyboard

Tags: keyboards

I've always had very cheap keyboards (like the KB216), and I would like to buy my first mechanical keyboard. Nevertheless I'm not yet ready to have a fully customized keyboard.

After testing different switches, my favorite one is the Cherry MX Brown. Thus I'm looking for a keyboard with an ISO Layout (french if possible), full or TKL, with RGB lights.
If I don't find any FR-ISO Layout, it needs to be an other ISO Layout where I can easily change the keycaps : I will buy an adapted set.
Also I'm mostly running on on Linux, for everyday work and even for gaming (saying that because of RGB support).

The best one I've found so far was the Everest Core. Do you recommend it? I've seen some bad and good reviews out there.

Or do you know any other good alternative? My budget range is between 150€ and 200€. I could spend a little more if it is worth it.

Comment: *[Everest Core](https://mountain.gg/everest-core/#)* does seem to have some macro capability, but it is not clear if it is all on the keyboard itself (it always ought to be) or if execution of macro keys require some kernel-level driver on Windows to work (hello, Corsair!). Is there a (downloadable) manual somewhere? Sometimes such information is directly or indirectly in the manual.